Leonardo Login with CloudFlare security
I am working with the automation for the leonardo.ai where there is CloudFlare checkbox, have tried to pass it even with manual process still i am stuck in a loop. i tried undetected_chromedriver also and it bypassed the thing for the first time, but after click on login it takes me to the login page again saying that captcha verification failed. even marking it manually making me in loop don't know what to do ? any help will be grateful.

def main():
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")  
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    file_path = 'D:\\Fiverr\\ideogram\\propmpts.xlsx'
    prompts = read_prompts_from_xlsx(file_path)
    os.makedirs('images', exist_ok=True)
    prompt_count = 0



def login(driver, email, password):
    print("let's login with new credentials")
    driver.get('https://app.leonardo.ai/auth/login')
    time.sleep(5)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')))
    email_field.send_keys(email)
    password_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')))
    password_field.send_keys(password)
    check = input("Please check the cloudflair: ")
    if(check != 'y'):
        print("Please try re run the script and select cloudflair security mannually")
    sign_in = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Sign in']")))
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", sign_in)
    sign_in.click()

